# Difference between namedtuple and a frozen dict

Tags: python, dictionary, namedtuple

I know there is no frozen dict data type but If there was one how would it be different from namedtuple. It seems to me that namedtuple performs the required operations but obviously it does not. So what are the differences?

Comment: Yeah but I mean it seems to perform the required operations to access a value by key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From an API viewpoint, probably not much, though:

- `namedtuple` keys are always strings with some limitations:

> Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname except for
>   names starting with an underscore. Valid identifiers consist of
>   letters, digits, and underscores but do not start with a digit or
>   underscore and cannot be a keyword such as class, for, return, global,
>   pass, or raise.

- `namedtuple`s can always be accessed as regular tuples.

Internally they are very different:

> Named tuple instances do not have per-instance dictionaries, so they
>   are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples.

Comment: Well, it's true `tuple`s are more compact that `dict`s, but `namedtuple`s have a completely different API from `dict`s. For example, by default you iterate over values, and `x in mynamedtuple` checks values. Furthermore, "keys" can be only strings, while a frozendict can have any hashable  type as keys, and so on.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is simple: A [`Dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is not a [`Tuple`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It's two totally different data structures.

Comment: "They're different" isn't an answer to the question "how are they different".

Comment: The question wasn't clear enough - he was asking about the difference between them as if they are the same and he can't tell the difference. Or perhaps I didn't understand the OP well :)